# Android WebView, view.capturePicture().getHeight() is 0

Tags: webview

I'm working on Android 4.0. I have a `WebView` where I want to capture its screen.
I Override the `WebViewClient` `onPageFinished` as folow:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Picture picture = view.capturePicture();
Toast.makeText(finplan.this, "picture height "+picture.getHeight()+ " url "+url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

in another procedure I call `loadUrl()`:

```
mywebview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com"); 
// this one works fine and picture.getHeight() is > 0

mywebview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html"); 
// this one works, but the picture.getHeight() retrieved in onPageFinished is always 0
```

test.html is a simple html file, I noticed later that any `loadUrl()` with `http//` works fine but doesn't works on `file://`. Any help in this ???

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
         Picture picture = view.capturePicture();
    }

});
webView.setPictureListener(new PictureListener() {

    public void onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture picture) {
        if (picture != null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "picture height " + picture.getHeight(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```